# How was Japan's involvement in the Korean war reconciled with Article 9 of the constitution?

Tags: constitution, armed-conflict, japan

The [Historical Basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Up_on_Poppy_Hill#Historical_basis) section of Wikipedia's article on the anime "From Up on Poppy Hill" indicates that the Japanese merchant marine and their crews carried forces and supplies to Korea during the Korean war.

How, if at all, was this reconciled with [Article 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_9_of_the_Japanese_Constitution) of the Japanese constitution?

Comment: I think it was never challenged in any court in Japan. But even it had been, the war was officially a UN "police action". Japan also officially renounced *arms*, but that was later re-interpreted to not apply to "defensive weapons".

Comment: Also, as one [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2146310) put it, the war was "almost invisible" in Japan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supreme court of Japan decided that some matters around article 9 are within the area of "political question", and that anything related to political question can not be decided by the judicial branch.

So, if someone in Japan had appealed  to the court, the court would have rejected the case.

Comment: This means they ruled article 9 null and void effectively?